# UIControl tracking and iOS 13 presentation style cards not working together

Tags: ios, ios13, uicontrol

I am using [AORangeSlider](https://github.com/Andy1984/AORangeSlider) which is a subclass of `UIControl` that overrides the `beginTracking`, `continueTracking` and `endTracking` methods.

When this control is added to a `viewController`, which is presented in iOS 13 using the "cards style", it has very strange behavior. When sliding the control the `viewController` will try to swipe down, and it interrupts the slider behavior and makes it unreliable and not work correctly.

[image]

If I instead, I present the `viewController` with `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` the control works correctly.

**Is there a way to allow the `AORangeSlider/UIControl` to work with the iOS 13 cards style of presentation and not have their touch events conflict?**

Comment: It sounds like there might be a problem with this control, since ordinary sliders don't have this issue. If you can't fix it by meddling with the control's code, you could turn off the swipe-down gesture for the presented view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to ask Apple about this, and they recommended the following solution, which worked:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in self.navigationController.presentationController.presentedView.gestureRecognizers) {
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    
}
```